# Java security grant permission in the policy file

Tags: java, security, content-security-policy

I enabled java security to grant file permission on the folder which resides in the /tmp folder. 
Below is the permission added in the grant file

```
permission "java.io.FilePermission" "/tmp/tmpScript/-", "read, write, delete, execute";
```

But while executing the application, exception thrown -

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "<<ALL FILES>>" "execute")
```

I'm using ProcessBuilder to execute the script and in the ProcessBuilder constructor file absolute path and argument is passed.
But looking at the Java source code

```
public void checkExec(String cmd) {
        File f = new File(cmd);
        if (f.isAbsolute()) {
            checkPermission(new FilePermission(cmd,
                SecurityConstants.FILE_EXECUTE_ACTION));
        } else {
            checkPermission(new FilePermission("<<ALL FILES>>",
                SecurityConstants.FILE_EXECUTE_ACTION));
        }
    }
```

Not sure why f.isAbsolute() is returning false therefore its trying to execute the else portion with file permission.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isAbsolute()

> File.isAbsolute() method returns true if this abstract pathname is
>   absolute, false otherwise

Judging from your permission command I am guessing you are using UNIX based system, Therefore absolute pathname meaning relates to this:

> On UNIX systems, a pathname is absolute if its prefix is "/"

This means that the cmd String variable, that is passed to checkExec function, prefix is not "/" (first character is not a '/'), therefore f.isAbsolute returns false.

Comment: I have prefix "/" added in the path but still it's returning the same file permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

ProcessBuilder works fine, I added /usr/bin permission and it worked.